# Creating Slider Through jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a code to create slider in HTML web page using JQUERY but its not working please help me following is the code for that. I have checked all the JS paths that are also proper. I have separated sliders code  to check and its worked but its not working when i will integrate that in following code.

```
    <html>                                                                  
 <head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">

     <link href="tms_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css">    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />                                                        

     <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>  





    <script src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script> 

   <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>



     <link rel="stylesheet" href="js_includes/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js_includes/development-bundle/demos/demos.css">


    <script src="js_includes/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="js_includes/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>



    <style>
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
    </style>

    <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('js_includes/development-bundle/demos/autocomplete/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(function() {

        $("#slider-range").slider({

            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 16000,
            values: [2000, 9000],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amountMin").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#amountMax").val(ui.values[1]);
            }
        });

        $("#amountMin").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
        $("#amountMax").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    });
    </script>


    <script>


        $(function() {



        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "AllResponse.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function( xmlResponse ) {
                var data = $( "Hotel", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                    return {
                        value: $( "CityCode", this ).text() + ", " +
                            ( $.trim( $( "CityName", this ).text() ) || "(unknown country)" ),
                        id: $( "CityCode", this ).text()
                    };
                }).get();
                $( "#txtCity" ).autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        log( ui.item ?
                            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + ", CityCode: " + ui.item.id :
                            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>







     <script>

    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            showButtonPanel: true


        });
    });
    </script>
     <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
    });
    </script>



<div style="display: none;" class="demo-description">
<p>The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.  Focus on the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a small overlay.  Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is shown as the input's value.</p>
</div>



 <script type="text/javascript">



     $(document).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "AllResponse.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: parseXml
         });




         function parseXml(document) {

             cnt = 1;
             var count = $(document).find("Hotel").each(function() {

             }).length;

          var Hotel = $(document).find("Hotel")
             Hotel.sort(function(a, b) {
             return (parseInt($(a).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')) - parseInt($(b).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')));
         });

         Hotel.each(function(i, v) {

         var title = $(v).find('OptionNo').text()
         var start = $(v).find('StayDateRange').attr('Start')
         var end = $(v).find('StayDateRange').attr('End')
         var Hotelname = $(v).find('Property').attr('HotelName')
         var CityName = $(v).find('CityName').text()
         var Address1 = $(v).find('Address1').text()
         var Address2 = $(v).find('Address2').text()
         var hotelimage = $(v).find('HotelFrontImage').attr('Url')
         var MinRate = $(v).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')
         var Currency = $(v).find('Property').attr('Currency')


         var NumberOfRooms = $(v).find('ManagementFeesDetails').text()
         var NumberOfRooms1 = $(v).find('Rooms').find('Room').attr('NumberOfRooms')

         var fullLink = '<div id="Hotel_details"> <div id="discounts_and_offers">Book 3 Days In Advance  And Get 15% Discount</div> <div id="hotel_image"><img src="' + hotelimage + '"/></div> <div id="hotel_view"><table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td height="89" ><div id="discount_rate">INR 8,325</div><div id="room_rate">' + Currency + ' ' + MinRate + '</div> Lowest room price <br />per night </td><tr><td height="39" ><img src="images/view_room.png" width="115" height="36"  /></td> </tr></table></div><div id="middle_div"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td height="94"><div id="hotel_information"><div id="hotel_header">' + Hotelname + '-' + CityName + '</div><div id="hotel_star_rating"><img src="images/star_rating.png" width="73" height="19" /></div><div id="hotel_info">' + Address1 + '<br>' + Address2 + '</div></div><div id="hotel_inclusions"><img src="images/inclusion1.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion2.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion3.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion4.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><br /><img src="images/inclusion5.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion6.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion7.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion8.jpg" width="17" height="16" /></div></td></tr><tr><td height="27"><div id="hotel_links"><ul><li>Details</li><li>|</li><li>Photos</li><li>|</li><li>Map</li></ul></div></td></tr></table></div>' + NumberOfRooms1 + '</div>';

         $("#content").append(fullLink);
         cnt = cnt + 1;
         //alert("Option is: " + $(v).find('OptionNo').text() + " Minimum Rate is " + $(v).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate') + " Call is " + $(v).find('Property').attr("Currency"));

         });
             paging(count);

         }

     });

function paging(count1) {
    var show_per_page = 8;
    var number_of_items = count1;
    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items / show_per_page);
    var current_link = 0;
    $('#current_page').val(0);
    $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);
    $("<a href='#'>Prev&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>").click(previous).appendTo("#page_navigation");
    while (number_of_pages > current_link) {
        $("<a href='#' class='page_link'>").text(++current_link + '  ').click(go_to_page).appendTo("#page_navigation")
    }
    $("<a href='#'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Next</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;").click(next).appendTo("#page_navigation");
    $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');
    $('#content').children().hide().slice(0, show_per_page).show();

    function previous(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Don't follow the link
        $(".active_page").prev(".page_link").click();
    }

    function next(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".active_page").next(".page_link").click();
    }

    function go_to_page(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the zero-based index instead of using an attribute
        var page_num = $(this).index(".page_link");

        //get the number of items shown per page
        var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

        //get the element number where to start the slice from
        start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

        //get the element number where to end the slice
        end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

        //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
        $('#content').children().hide().slice(start_from, end_on).show();

        //Since this always points to the page link, use that instead of looking for it
        $(this).addClass("active_page").siblings(".active_page").removeClass("active_page");
    }
}

function getXml() {


    var city=document.getElementById("txtCity").value;
    var checkin=document.getElementById("datepicker1").value;
    var checkout=document.getElementById("datepicker2").value;
    var sortBy = $("#sortBy").val();



    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "AllResponse.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml2
    });




    function parseXml2(document) {


        $("#content").text("");
        $("#page_navigation").text("");
        cnt = 0;
        var count = $(document).find("Hotel").each(function() {

    }).length;
    if (sortBy == 1) {
        var Hotel = $(document).find("Hotel")
        Hotel.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (parseInt($(a).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')) - parseInt($(b).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')));
        });
    }
    else {
        var Hotel = $(document).find("Hotel")
        Hotel.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (parseInt($(b).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')) - parseInt($(a).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')));
        });
    }

    Hotel.each(function(i, v) {

        // Criteria Find For Only Hotels 
        var title = $(v).find('OptionNo').text()
        var start = $(v).find('StayDateRange').attr('Start')
        var end = $(v).find('StayDateRange').attr('End')
        var Hotelname = $(v).find('Property').attr('HotelName')
        var CityName = $(v).find('CityName').text()
        var Address1 = $(v).find('Address1').text()
        var Address2 = $(v).find('Address2').text()
        var hotelimage = $(v).find('HotelFrontImage').attr('Url')
        var MinRate = $(v).find('Property').attr('MinimumRate')
        var Currency = $(v).find('Property').attr('Currency')


        var NumberOfRooms = $(v).find('ManagementFeesDetails').text()
        var NumberOfRooms1 = $(v).find('Rooms').find('Room').attr('NumberOfRooms')

        //**************************************************************

        // Criteria Find For Hotel Rooms

        if (CityName == city.toUpperCase() && start >= checkin && end <= checkout) {
            cnt = cnt + 1;

            var fullLink = '<div id="Hotel_details"> <div id="discounts_and_offers">Book 3 Days In Advance  And Get 15% Discount</div> <div id="hotel_image"><img src="' + hotelimage + '" /></div> <div id="hotel_view"><table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td height="89" ><div id="discount_rate">INR 8,325</div><div id="room_rate">' + Currency + ' ' + MinRate + '</div> Lowest room price <br />per night </td><tr><td height="39" ><img src="images/view_room.png" width="115" height="36"  /></td> </tr></table></div><div id="middle_div"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td height="94"><div id="hotel_information"><div id="hotel_header">' + Hotelname + '-' + CityName + '</div><div id="hotel_star_rating"><img src="images/star_rating.png" width="73" height="19" /></div><div id="hotel_info">' + Address1 + '<br>' + Address2 + '</div></div><div id="hotel_inclusions"><img src="images/inclusion1.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion2.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion3.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion4.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><br /><img src="images/inclusion5.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion6.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion7.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion8.jpg" width="17" height="16" /></div></td></tr><tr><td height="27"><div id="hotel_links"><ul><li>Details</li><li>|</li><li>Photos</li><li>|</li><li>Map</li></ul></div></td></tr></table></div></div>';

            $("#content").append(fullLink);

        }
        else if (city == "" || checkin == "" || checkout == "") {
            cnt = cnt + 1;

            var fullLink = '<div id="Hotel_details"> <div id="discounts_and_offers">Book 3 Days In Advance  And Get 15% Discount</div> <div id="hotel_image"><img src="' + hotelimage + '" /></div> <div id="hotel_view"><table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td height="89" ><div id="discount_rate">INR 8,325</div><div id="room_rate">' + Currency + ' ' + MinRate + '</div> Lowest room price <br />per night </td><tr><td height="39" ><img src="images/view_room.png" width="115" height="36"  /></td> </tr></table></div><div id="middle_div"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td height="94"><div id="hotel_information"><div id="hotel_header">' + Hotelname + '-' + CityName + '</div><div id="hotel_star_rating"><img src="images/star_rating.png" width="73" height="19" /></div><div id="hotel_info">' + Address1 + '<br>' + Address2 + '</div></div><div id="hotel_inclusions"><img src="images/inclusion1.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion2.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion3.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion4.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><br /><img src="images/inclusion5.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion6.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion7.jpg" width="17" height="16" /><img src="images/inclusion8.jpg" width="17" height="16" /></div></td></tr><tr><td height="27"><div id="hotel_links"><ul><li>Details</li><li>|</li><li>Photos</li><li>|</li><li>Map</li></ul></div></td></tr></table></div></div>';

            $("#content").append(fullLink);

        }
    });


        //alert(cnt);
        paging(cnt);
    }

}



 </script>                                                               
 </head>                                                                 
 <body>  

 <div class="demo">
<div id="sarchBox">
<form name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" method="post">

    <label for="txtCity">City : </label>
    <input id="txtCity" type="text" />


Check-In: <input type="text" id="datepicker1">


Check-Out: <input type="text" id="datepicker2">



<input type="button" id="search" value="search" onClick="getXml();" />
</form>
</div>




<input type="hidden" id="current_page" />
<input type="hidden" id="show_per_page" />
<div>Sort By Price: <select id="sortBy" onChange="getXml();">
<option value="1" >Low To Heigh</option>
<option value="2">Heigh To Low</option></select></div>

<b style="font-size:medium;">Price Range:</b><br>

<div id="slider-range"></div>

    <b  style="font-size:small;">Rs:</b>
    <input type="text" id="amountMin" size="19" readonly="readonly" style="font-size:small; border:0; color:#f6931f; background-color:#DEDEDE; font-weight:bold;" />
    <b  style="font-size:small;">Rs:</b>
    <input type="text" id="amountMax" size="4" readonly="readonly" style="font-size:small; border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; background-color:#DEDEDE;" />

</div>


<ul id="content"></ul>



 <div id="page_navigation" ></div>


</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

Following is the code for slider from above

```
<script>
        $(function() {

            $("#slider-range").slider({

                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 16000,
                values: [2000, 9000],
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#amountMin").val(ui.values[0]);
                    $("#amountMax").val(ui.values[1]);
                }
            });

            $("#amountMin").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
            $("#amountMax").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: any javascript errors? check your console output (in Chrome, CTRL + SHIFT + I, then click console tab)

Comment: Not on topic of the issue as I'm waiting for you to respond to Musefan, but you should really put all those UI files into one to save the browser sending lots of requests.